# how to swap all rows in an array

Tags: python, numpy

I try to rotate the matrix so that the first line is the last and the last is the first. And proceed in this way with the other lines in array

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
              [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
              [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
              [41, 42, 43, 44, 45]])
```

My attempt:

```
p = np.rot90(m, 2)
array([[45, 44, 43, 42, 41],
       [35, 34, 33, 32, 31],
       [25, 24, 23, 22, 21],
       [15, 14, 13, 12, 11]])
```

I need

```
array([[41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Isn't it ```m[::-1,]```

Answer (score 1):

```
np.flip(m,axis=0)
```

#### output

```
array([[41, 42, 43, 44, 45],
       [31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially trying to flip the matrix vertically and the function is literally `flipud`:

```
np.flipud(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from [`flipud(m)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flipud.html) and [`flip(m, axis=0)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), you can use simple indexing to reverse the first dimension:

```
m[::-1, :]
```

or even just

```
m[::-1]
```

If you really wanted arcane overkill, you could do something with [`np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(m[-1], shape=m.shape, strides=(-m.strides[0], m.strides[1]))
```